# MongoDB $unwind field name conflict

Tags: mongodb

Schema: {title: '', author: '', post: '', comments: [{author:'', comments: ''}]}

Would there be 2 **author**s in the new document as a result of **$unwind: "$comments"**? How to give a new field name to comments.author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$unwind` outputs a document for each element in the array. Each new document has the array replaced by one of the elements in the array. In this case, because it is an array of embedded documents, the output of the new field will be an embedded document, named `comments` and with the fields `author` and `comments`.

So there will not be a conflict, as the `author` field will be embedded in the `comments` field.

The easiest way to see this is to try it yourself:

```
db.test.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$comments"  }]);
```

Outputs:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e76c41ca8a53ab3b4e827b"), 
    "title" : "", 
    "author" : "", 
    "post" : "", 
    "comments" : { "author" : "", "comments" : "" } 
}
```

If you did want to flatten the embedded document and rename the field, you would add a [$project stage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) into the aggregation pipeline after the `$unwind`.